# Drop number of rows in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe contain 25000 rows with two columns (text ,  class)
class contains a number of [A,B,C]

```
data = pd.read_csv('E:\mydata.txt', sep="*")
data.columns = ["text", "class"]
```

I need delete for example 10 rows of class A, 15 rows of class B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with conditional slicing and the index property of dataframes

```
remove_n = 10
remove_class = 1
# Here you first find the indexes where class is equal to the class you want to drop.
#Then you slice only the first n indexes of this class
index_to_drop = data.index[data['class'] == remove_class][:remove_n]
#Finally drop those indexes
data = data.drop(index_to_drop)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a single Boolean mask via [`np.logical_and`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html) and [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html). Then apply it to your dataframe via [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
# example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'group': np.random.randint(0, 3, 100),
                   'value': np.random.random(100)})

print(df.shape)  # (100, 2)

# criteria input
criteria = {1: 10, 2: 15}

# cumulative count by group
cum_count = df.groupby('group').cumcount()

# Boolean mask, negative via ~
conditions = [(df['group'].eq(k) & cum_count.lt(v)) for k, v in criteria.items()]
mask = ~np.logical_or.reduce(conditions)

# apply Boolean mask
res = df.iloc[mask]

print(res.shape)  # (75, 2)
```